# not got exiftool syntax( pretty basic)

Tags: perl, exiftool

I am trying to learn perl because it does arrays and I want to manipulate some images.
I'm not quite sure exactly what an object is.
In the explanations about Image::ExifTool it says that the example syntax can be used to get information from an open file.
Presumably this means a file in memory with a token (is that the correct expression)? pointing to the bits of memory ?
What is the syntax in perl to open a file so that I can get the keys from it ?
cheers

Answer (score 1):

Since [`Image::ExifTool`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/EXIFTOOL/Image-ExifTool-9.60/lib/Image/ExifTool.pod) refers to open file handle,

```
open my $fh, "<:raw", "picture.jpg" or die $!;
# ...

# return information about an open image file (object-oriented)
my $info = $exifTool->ImageInfo($fh);
```